# Max function django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the relationship follow as:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  content = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Answer(models.Model):
  content = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
  num_vote = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to retrieve the answers, which have the max voting. I tried this statement but it isn't correctly.

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question__exact=1).annotate(Max('num_vote'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some predefined number of answers? You you need e.g. 5 high-scored answers use

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=somequestion).order_by('-num_vote')[:5]
```

If you need all the answers with max `num_vote` you need 2 queries.

```
max_score = Answer.objects.filter(question=somequestion).aggregate(score=Max('num_vote'))
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=somequestion, num_vote=max_score['score'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to get all answers for a specific `Question`, then you have to use an instance of the `Question`:

```
question = Question.objects.get(...)
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=question).annotate(Max('num_vote'))
```

Second, the above may be the reason for your problems?

Comment: Thank Joachim Pileborg. But I want to retrieve the answers that have the max num_vote. E.g. There are 3 answers. Answer 1 has 3 num_vote. Answer 2 has 1 num_vote and Answer 3 has 3 num_vote. So, the result is <Answer1, Answer3>